# Sum the total of a column based on a value disregarding duplicate in another column - access or excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been searching in a way of sum the total of "corrections" in a database based on a "key" column where "submissions" are unique.

I found a way to calculate the what I need in excel, but when used on VBA the calculation gets unpractical as it takes over 50 mins to run in a fle of 9000 rows, and that's just a sample.

the excel formula I found is the SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIF as per below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($T$2:$T$40=T2)*$I$2:$I$40/COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$40,$N$2:$N$40)) (where T = Key; I= Corrections and N= Submissions)
```

As I cant get excel to reduce time when added to VBA, I was wondering If could add it to the access database where I take the raw data from.

[image]

Comment: A) I wouldn't use sumproduct and countif together in excel (at least not how you're using it)... you have the capability of using an if statement to eliminate data and can loop cell to cell, which should take a second or two.  B)  what is going on in your countif?

Comment: I can't speak to the Access side, but I would recommend that if you're goign to try this in VBA, to 1) determine a UNIQUE list of keys in a 2 dimension array, 2) loop through your sheet row by row, 3) look up the key in the unique array and add to the second element of said array, 4) output the array.  that should save a bit of additional efforts and keeps the math in VBA to save time rather than updating/etc. within Excel

Comment: Hi @Cyril, thank you for your output, my file has 35 columns and over 52K rows, I have also several sumifs in other columns for time and other specific counts that are not on this example, all together the vba took only 5 minutes to run the 52K rows and fill everything, but when I realised that the duplication on "Submission" should not be counted I had to add the sumproduct, since I have to base the count to the specific "key". once I added this calculation into excel, run a sample of 9k rows took over 50 minutes.

Comment: Could you share the VBA code? I cannot connect the dots. What is searched where, checked against what? How did you get the data in column Total of Corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to accomplish this in MS Access, you could use the following query:

```sql
select q.key, sum(q.corrections) as [Total of Corrections]
from (select distinct t.submission, t.corrections, t.key from YourTable t) q
group by q.key
```

(Change `YourTable` to suit your table name)

If you wanted to output the total as part of the original data, per your screenshot, you could use:

```sql
select t.*, s.[total of corrections]
from YourTable t inner join 
(
    select q.key, sum(q.corrections) as [total of corrections]
    from (select distinct t.submission, t.corrections, t.key from YourTable t) q
    group by q.key
) s on t.key = s.key
```

(Again, change both occurrences of `YourTable` to suit your table name)

Answer (score 0):

VBA as requested, its my first attempt creating something like these so please forgive me for the mess, all the below was put together using forums like this one, I just got stuck with the above scenario, so I decided to increase my columns and separate the formula to work inside excel.
I create a count if to find the duplicates and divide the total of corrections per submission in the end using a new column. Thank you very much for your help:

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim C_Sheet As String, C_LastRow As Long, D_LastRow As Long

C_Sheet = "ProductivityFinal"
C_LastRow = Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("N:N").End(xlDown).Row 'count col for Claim ID (no blank expected)
'C_LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim TmpFolder As String, TmpFile As String, BUfile As String

TmpFolder = "X:\Productivity Report\" 'live folder

TmpFile = "ProductivityFinal.xlsx"
BUfile = "BU_ProductivityFinal.xlsx"

If Dir(TmpFolder & TmpFile) = "" Then 'check if temp file exists
    MsgBox "No data file exists. Please run report."
Exit Sub
End If

If MsgBox("It may take some time. Closing unnecessary files would help to speed up." & vbCrLf & "Continue?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("Summary").Select
Call Shaper1
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Workbooks.Open TmpFolder & TmpFile
D_LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

'Clearing data sheets before import
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets(C_Sheet).Select
Call ClearTable1

'Fetch data and paste
Workbooks(TmpFile).Activate
    Sheets("ProductivityFinal").Select
    Range("A2:T" & D_LastRow).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets(C_Sheet).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A2").Select

'--Sorting--
Call SortingTable
'-----------




Workbooks(TmpFile).Activate

'Take backup and delete original temp file.
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(TmpFile).SaveAs Filename:=TmpFolder & BUfile
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks(BUfile).Close
On Error GoTo 0

Kill TmpFolder & TmpFile


Call HeaderAndFormula


Sheets("Summary").Select
Call RefreshingPivot
'--------------


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Call Shaper4
MsgBox "Updated"

End Sub

Sub HeaderAndFormula()

Dim C_Sheet As String, C_LastRow As Long
C_Sheet = "ProductivityFinal"

C_LastRow = Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("N:N").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Config").Range("B4").Value = C_LastRow

'Header
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("A1:AE1").Value = Sheets("Config").Range("A10:AE10").Value

'Formulas

Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("A1").Select

Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("U2").Value = "=O2/I2"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("W2").Value = "=V2/G2"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("Z2").Value = "=X2*1"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AA2").Value = "=TIMEVALUE(M:M)"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AE2").Value = "=AA2-AB2-AD2"


Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("X2").Value = "=IF(P2=Q2,IF(T3=T2,IF(K3<J2,(K2-J2),""STARTED BEFORE SUBMITTING LAST CLAIM""),IF(P2=Q2,(K2-J2))),""Assigned Overnight"")"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("Y2").Value = "=IF(T3=T2,IF(J2-K3<0,""ERROR"",J2-K3),""FIRST CLAIM OF THE DAY"")"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AB2").Value = "=SUMIF(T:T,T2,Z:Z)"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AC2").Value = "=IF(Y2=""FIRST CLAIM OF THE DAY"", 0, Y2*1)"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AD2").Value = "=SUMIF(T:T,T2,AC:AC)"

'Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AF2").Value = "=I2/COUNTIFS(T:T,T2,N:N,N:N)"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("AF2").Value = "=I2/COUNTIFS($T$2:INDIRECT(""$T$"" & Config!$B$4),T2,$N$2:INDIRECT(""$N$"" & Config!$B$4),$N$2:INDIRECT(""$N$"" & Config!$B$4))"

'Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("V2").Value = "=SUMIF(T:T,T2,I:I)"
'Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("V2").Value = "=SUMPRODUCT(($T$2:INDIRECT(""$T$"" & Config!$B$4)=T2)*$I$2:INDIRECT(""$I$"" & Config!$B$4)/COUNTIFS($N$2:INDIRECT(""$N$"" & Config!$B$4),$N$2:INDIRECT(""$N$"" & Config!$B$4)))"

'Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("V2").Value = "=SUMIF(T:T,T2,AF:AF)"
Sheets(C_Sheet).Range("V2").Value = "=SUMIF($T$2:INDIRECT(""$T$"" & Config!$B$4),T2,$AF$2:INDIRECT(""$AF$"" & Config!$B$4))"


'Autofill
'N:14, U:21 , AF: 32
Range("U2:AF2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 21), Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 18))


Sheets("Summary").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call Shaper2

Call Shaper3
Sheets("Summary").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(C_Sheet).Select


'Sheets("ProductivityFinal").Range("U:AF").Calculate
Sheets("ProductivityFinal").Range("U2:AF" & Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row).Calculate


'Recover Pivot Reference


Sheets("Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "ProductivityFinal!$A$1:$AE$" & C_LastRow, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

End Sub
Sub ClearTable1()
Sheets("ProductivityFinal").Select
If Range("N2") = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Rows("2:1048561").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("U2:AE2").ClearContents 'remove formula
Sheets("ProductivityFinal").Range("A2:T2").Value = Sheets("Config").Range("A15:T15").Value 'feed sample data
End Sub

Sub RefreshingPivot() 'all pivot tables
'Dim PT As PivotTable   
'Dim WS As Worksheet
'
'    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
'          PT.RefreshTable
'        Next PT
'    Next WS

'Sheets("Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub

Sub SortingTable() 'sort *** [Key](A to Z) first then [Since Dt](Z to A).

'Format cells----
Columns("J:K").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Columns("P:Q").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Columns("X:AE").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
'----


Range("A1:AE1").AutoFilter

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductivityFinal").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductivityFinal").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("T1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductivityFinal").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductivityFinal").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("J1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductivityFinal").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Range("A1:AE1").AutoFilter
End Sub
Sub Shaper1() 'Import logo to appear
Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Rectangle 13").Left = 500
End Sub
Sub Shaper2() 'Import logo to disappear
Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Rectangle 13").Left = 5000
Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Rectangle 13").Top = 100
End Sub
Sub Shaper3() 'Calc logo to appear
Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Rectangle 14").Left = 500
End Sub
Sub Shaper4() 'Calc logo to disappear
Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Rectangle 14").Left = 5000
Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Rectangle 14").Top = 100
End Sub
```